# Cloud Foundry: How to remap an exposed port in Docker image?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I would like to run RabbitMQ service using my organization's Cloud Foundry Service. I checked the RabbitMQ docker image and saw that the following ports are exposed:

```
 "ExposedPorts": {
                "25672/tcp": {},
                "4369/tcp": {},
                "5671/tcp": {},
                "5672/tcp": {}
            },
```

I start the app by installing it in Cloud Foundry as follows: `cf push -o rabbitmq RabbitMQ -u process`.

The app gets installed and gets started. However, it is listening on port 5672. The CF service only allows me to have ports between 10000 and 10999. So I go into the CF portal, remove the HTTP route, and create a new TCP route on port 10123 for the rabbitmq app.

How do I go about mapping the port 10123 (external facing) to the port 5672 (RabbitMQ, internal facing) using the CF CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is functionality to map a route with specific external ports to specific internal app ports. It is described in the docs here.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/custom-ports.html#procedure

At the moment, the functionality isn't directly supported by the cf cli, so you need to use `cf curl` to manually send a few requests.

The general flow is this.

1. Get your app's guid.
2. Configure a list of ports for your app, `cf curl /v2/apps/APP-GUID -X PUT -d '{"ports": [25672, 4369, 5671, 5672]}'`
3. Map a TCP route to your app with `cf map-route my-app example.com --port 10123`.
4. Get the route guid of your TCP routee. Run `cf curl /v2/routes?q=host:example.com`.
5. Update the route mapping with `cf curl /v2/route_mappings -X POST -d '{"app_guid": "APP-GUID from #1", "route_guid": "ROUTE-GUID from #4", "app_port": 5672}'`
6. Optionally repeat 3-5 for additional ports.